# Resty - IllegalArgumentException with | character in URL

Tags: java, api, rest, url

I use Resty client for handling Facebook REST API. The problem is that I want to use "|" character in Facebook token as it is in the doc:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/800309809778160/permissions?access_token=861093975893683|t5r-lFvnrsEQ_xTtUsdMuiEdFdsdE
```

When I paste this URL to the browser - works fine. But when I do it using Resty, (new Resty().text(url)) it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 83: https://graph.facebook.com/800309809778160/permissions?access_token=861093975893683|t5r-lFvnrsEQ_xTtUsdMuiEdFdsdE
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at us.monoid.web.Resty.text(Resty.java:271)
```

I wonder if I should use another REST client (like HTTPUrlConnection or Rapa), or the reason is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to encode special characters in url like "&" , "?" with their encoding value**

> instead of "|" pass "%7C" in url

check complete list of encoding value of character at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: so silly! thanks a lot. Of course I went this route, but by mistake I used %2F instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the | character in the URL with %7C

```
https://graph.facebook.com/800309809778160/permissions?access_token=861093975893683%7Ct5r-lFvnrsEQ_xTtUsdMuiEdFdsdE
```

You can checkout more escape character here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: thanks, that's a right answer, but unfortunately Keval was first :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode()
```